# Solving complex bin packing problem with GEKKO

Tags: optimization, gekko, bin-packing

I am trying to solve a 2D circle bin packing problem, where the objective is to minimize the number of bins used. The items are circles with varying sizes and the required amount of bins is not known. So from a worst-case scenario the upper bound for number of bins is equal to number of items to be packed.

The variables include

- `x[i,b]` whether item `i` is packed in bin `b`
- `y[b]` whether bin `b` is used
- `cx[i,b]` and `cy[i,b]`, center coordinates for item `i` in bin `b`.

When I run my model, GEKKO says that there is no solution found. I have implemented the same methodology in OR-Tools, but because it does not support non-linear equations it is not feasible for my use case, when the number of items or bins needed grows.

My code is currently following:

```py
"""
Initialize solver
"""
solver = GEKKO(remote=False)
solver.options.SOLVER = 1   # Try also 0 and 3

"""
Create data model
"""
data = {}
data['items'] = list(range(len(group)))
data['pallets'] = list(range(len(group)))
data['pallet_length'] = pallet_dimensions[0] # x-dimension of pallet
data['pallet_width'] = pallet_dimensions[1]  # y-dimension of pallet
data['pallet_area'] = pallet_dimensions[2]

"""
Variables
"""
# x[i, b] = 1 if item i is packed in pallet b.
x = {}
for i in data['items']:
    for b in data['pallets']:
        x[(i, b)] = solver.Var(0, lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)

# y[b] = 1 if pallet b is used
y = {}
for j in data['pallets']:
    y[j] = solver.Var(0, lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)

# Center X and Y coodinates for stack i in pallet b
cx = {}
cy = {}
for b in data['pallets']:
    for i, stack in enumerate(group):
        cx[(i,b)] = solver.Var(lb=stack._radius,
                               ub=data['pallet_length']-stack._radius,
                               integer=True)
        cy[(i,b)] = solver.Var(lb=stack._radius,
                               ub=data['pallet_width'] -stack._radius,
                               integer=True)

"""
Constaints
"""
# Each item must be in exactly one pallet.
for i in data['items']:
    solver.Equation( sum( x[(i, b)] for b in data['pallets'] ) == 1 )

# Pallet size constraint, the area of packed stacks
#   cannot exceed the pallet area.
for b in data['pallets']:
    solver.Equation( sum( x[(i, b)] * stack.area for i, stack in enumerate(group) ) <= y[b] * data['pallet_area'] )

# Enforce no overlap on stack items. Distance between stack
#    i and j equal or over to the sum of their radii.
for b in data['pallets']:
    for i in range(len(group) - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(group)):
            # sqrt( (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 ) >= r2+r1 
            solver.Equation(solver.sqrt( (cx[(j,b)]-cx[(i,b)])**2 +
                            (cy[(j,b)]-cy[(i,b)])**2 ) >= 
                            (group[i]._radius + group[j]._radius) )
    
"""
Objective
"""
# Minimize the number of bins used.
solver.Minimize( solver.sum( [y[b] for b in data['pallets']] ) )

"""
Solve
"""
solver.solve( disp=True )
```

It looks like the no-overlap constraint is not working, because the model works if I remove that. But it is the most important part. Can you either find an error or an problem with my implementation logic?

Comment: a couple shots in the dark here, but....  try removing the integer requirement for cx and cy, and/or remove the square root from the formulation and just work with "squared distance" to remove the root.  aka...  `(x_1 - x_2)**2 + (y_1-y_2)**2 >= (r1 + r2)**2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a related optimization problem and solution for [circle packing optimization](https://apmonitor.com/me575/uploads/Main/10_circle_packing_anim.gif):

[image: circle packing]

More specific answers can be suggested with a complete and minimal example. Here is a version with sample data that reproduces the error:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO

"""
Add test data
"""
pallet_dimensions = [1,3,2]
group = [None]*5
radius = 0.2
area = 0.1

"""
Initialize solver
"""
solver = GEKKO(remote=False)
solver.options.SOLVER = 1   # Try also 0 and 3

"""
Create data model
"""
data = {}
data['items'] = list(range(len(group)))
data['pallets'] = list(range(len(group)))
data['pallet_length'] = pallet_dimensions[0] # x-dimension of pallet
data['pallet_width'] = pallet_dimensions[1]  # y-dimension of pallet
data['pallet_area'] = pallet_dimensions[2]

"""
Variables
"""
# x[i, b] = 1 if item i is packed in pallet b.
x = {}
for i in data['items']:
    for b in data['pallets']:
        x[(i, b)] = solver.Var(0, lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)

# y[b] = 1 if pallet b is used
y = {}
for j in data['pallets']:
    y[j] = solver.Var(0, lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)

# Center X and Y coodinates for stack i in pallet b
cx = {}
cy = {}
for b in data['pallets']:
    for i, stack in enumerate(group):
        cx[(i,b)] = solver.Var(lb=radius,
                               ub=data['pallet_length']-radius,
                               integer=True)
        cy[(i,b)] = solver.Var(lb=radius,
                               ub=data['pallet_width'] -radius,
                               integer=True)

"""
Constaints
"""
# Each item must be in exactly one pallet.
for i in data['items']:
    solver.Equation( sum( x[(i, b)] for b in data['pallets'] ) == 1 )

# Pallet size constraint, the area of packed stacks
#   cannot exceed the pallet area.
for b in data['pallets']:
    solver.Equation(sum(x[(i,b)]*area for i, stack in enumerate(group))
                      <= y[b] * data['pallet_area'])

# Enforce no overlap on stack items. Distance between stack
#    i and j equal or over to the sum of their radii.
for b in data['pallets']:
    for i in range(len(group) - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(group)):
            # sqrt( (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 ) >= r2+r1 
            solver.Equation(solver.sqrt( (cx[(j,b)]-cx[(i,b)])**2 +
                            (cy[(j,b)]-cy[(i,b)])**2 ) >= 
                            (radius + radius) )
    
"""
Objective
"""
# Minimize the number of bins used.
solver.Minimize( solver.sum( [y[b] for b in data['pallets']] ) )

"""
Solve
"""
solver.solve( disp=True )
```

*Results*

```
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I: -1 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    2 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    0 Obj:  0.00E+00 Gap:       NaN
 Warning: no more possible trial points and no integer solution
 Maximum iterations
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :  0.026099999999999984 sec
 Objective      :  0.
 Unsuccessful with error code  0
 ---------------------------------------------------
 
 Creating file: infeasibilities.txt
 Use command apm_get(server,app,'infeasibilities.txt') to retrieve file
 @error: Solution Not Found

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\johnh\Desktop\test.py", line 86, in <module>
    solver.solve( disp=True )
  File "C:\Users\johnh\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gekko\gekko.py", line 2140, in solve
    raise Exception(apm_error)
Exception: @error: Solution Not Found
```

A few modifications may help find a solution. I've included the suggestions from [AirSquid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10789207/airsquid) and also made a few additional changes.

- Initialize with IPOPT

```py
solver.options.SOLVER = 3
solver.solve( disp=True )

solver.options.SOLVER = 1
solver.solve( disp=True )
```

- Try an inequality constraint. It should still be equal to 1.0 at the solution, but it is easier for the solver to find a solution by looking in the infeasible space.

```py
# Each item must be in exactly one pallet.
for i in data['items']:
    solver.Equation( sum( x[(i, b)] for b in data['pallets'] ) >= 1 )
```

Here is a complete script with a successful solution:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO

"""
Add test data
"""
pallet_dimensions = [5,3,2]
group = [None]*3
radius = 0.1
area = 0.1


"""
Initialize solver
"""
solver = GEKKO(remote=False)
solver.options.SOLVER = 1   # Try also 0 and 3

"""
Create data model
"""
data = {}
data['items'] = list(range(len(group)))
data['pallets'] = list(range(len(group)))
data['pallet_length'] = pallet_dimensions[0] # x-dimension of pallet
data['pallet_width'] = pallet_dimensions[1]  # y-dimension of pallet
data['pallet_area'] = pallet_dimensions[2]

"""
Variables
"""
# x[i, b] = 1 if item i is packed in pallet b.
x = {}
for i in data['items']:
    for b in data['pallets']:
        x[(i, b)] = solver.Var(0.5, lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)

# y[b] = 1 if pallet b is used
y = {}
for j in data['pallets']:
    y[j] = solver.Var(0.1, lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)

# Center X and Y coodinates for stack i in pallet b
cx = {}
cy = {}
for b in data['pallets']:
    for i, stack in enumerate(group):
        cx[(i,b)] = solver.Var(lb=radius,
                               ub=data['pallet_length']-radius)
        cy[(i,b)] = solver.Var(lb=radius,
                               ub=data['pallet_width'] -radius)

"""
Constaints
"""
# Each item must be in exactly one pallet.
for i in data['items']:
    solver.Equation( sum( x[(i, b)] for b in data['pallets'] ) >= 1 )
    
# Pallet size constraint, the area of packed stacks
#   cannot exceed the pallet area.
for b in data['pallets']:
    solver.Equation(sum(x[(i,b)]*area for i, stack in enumerate(group))
                      <= y[b] * data['pallet_area'])

# Enforce no overlap on stack items. Distance between stack
#    i and j equal or over to the sum of their radii.
for b in data['pallets']:
    for i in range(len(group) - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(group)):
            # sqrt( (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 ) >= r2+r1 
            solver.Equation((cx[(j,b)]-cx[(i,b)])**2 +
                            (cy[(j,b)]-cy[(i,b)])**2 >= 
                            (radius + radius)**2 )
    
"""
Objective
"""
# Minimize the number of bins used.
solver.Minimize( solver.sum( [y[b] for b in data['pallets']] ) )

"""
Solve
"""
solver.options.SOLVER = 3
solver.solve( disp=True )

solver.options.SOLVER = 1
solver.solve( disp=True )

print(x)
```

*Results for `x`*

```
{(0, 0): [0.0], (0, 1): [0.0], (0, 2): [1.0],
 (1, 0): [0.0], (1, 1): [0.0], (1, 2): [1.0],
 (2, 0): [0.0], (2, 1): [0.0], (2, 2): [1.0]}
```

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. This indeed work for your test case and I am able to reproduce that, but when I try to use real examples from my dataset, the solver is not able to find a solution.

For example this case, where
item_radius = [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]
item_areas = [0.12568, 0.12568, 0.12568, 0.12568]
pallet_dimensions = [0.8, 0.8, 0.64]

Comment: Clarifying further: I need the radii and areas of items to be in arrays, because they can have varying sizes.

Comment: Again, with further testing, I found a case where the solver finds a solution when all the items can fit onto one pallet, but does not find solution with smaller pallet size.

Works:
Item radii:  [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]
Item areas:  [0.12568, 0.12568, 0.12568, 0.12568, 0.12568, 0.12568]
Pallet length:  1.2
Pallet width:  0.8
Pallet area:  0.96

Doesn't work
Item radii:  [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]
Item areas:  [0.12568, 0.12568, 0.12568, 0.12568, 0.12568, 0.12568]
Pallet length:  0.8
Pallet width:  0.8
Pallet area:  0.64

Comment: Thanks for those insights. Please create a new question with that specific case. It is helpful to have a complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Discussion continues in the new question thread in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76051166/problem-to-solve-complex-bin-packing-cases-with-gekko