# Problem to solve complex bin packing cases with GEKKO

Tags: python, optimization, gekko, bin-packing

Continuation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76034466/solving-complex-bin-packing-problem-with-gekko).

I am trying to solve a 2D circle bin packing problem, where the objective is to minimize the number of bins used. The items are circles with varying sizes and the required amount of bins is not known. So from a worst-case scenario the upper bound for number of bins is equal to number of items to be packed.

The variables include

- x[i,b] whether item i is packed in bin b
- y[b] whether bin b is used
- cx[i,b] and cy[i,b], center coordinates for item i in bin b.

I have gotten the model to work with small and simple cases. But currently I found a case where the solver is able to find a packing solution for 6 items in a bigger pallet, but for a smaller pallet the solver says, there is no solution found. I think, that the problem is that my model is not able to pack items into more than one pallet.

My model is as follows

```
"""
Initialize solver
"""
solver = GEKKO(remote=False)
solver.options.SOLVER = 1   # 1=APOPT, 3=IPOPT

"""
Create data model
"""
items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]                                          # Item IDs
radii = [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]                              # Radii of all items in m
areas = [0.12568, 0.12568, 0.12568, 0.12568, 0.12568, 0.12568]      # Areas of items in m2
pallets = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]                                        # Pallet IDs
pallet_length = 1.2                                                 # x-dimension of pallet in m
pallet_width = 0.8                                                  # y-dimension of pallet in m
pallet_area = 0.96                                                  # pallet area in m2

# Debug printing
print(f"Item IDs:  {items}")
print(f"Item radii:  {radii}")
print(f"Item areas:  {areas}")
print(f"Pallet IDs:  {pallets}")
print(f"Pallet length:  {pallet_length}")
print(f"Pallet width:  {pallet_width}")
print(f"Pallet area:  {pallet_area}")

"""
Variables
"""
# x[i, b] = 1 if item i is packed in pallet b.
x = {}
for i in items:
    for b in pallets:
        x[(i, b)] = solver.Var(0.5, lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)

# y[b] = 1 if pallet b is used
y = {}
for j in pallets:
    y[j] = solver.Var(0.5, lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)

# Center X and Y coodinates for stack i in pallet b
cx = {}
cy = {}
for b in pallets:
    for i in range(len(radii)):
        cx[(i,b)] = solver.Var(lb=radii[i], ub=pallet_length-radii[i])
        cy[(i,b)] = solver.Var(lb=radii[i], ub=pallet_width -radii[i])
    
"""
Constaints
"""
# Each item must be in exactly one pallet.
for i in items:
    solver.Equation( sum( x[(i, b)] for b in pallets ) >= 1 )

# Pallet size constraint, the area of packed stacks cannot exceed the pallet area.
for b in pallets:
    solver.Equation( sum(x[(i,b)] * areas[i] for i in range(len(areas))) <= y[b] * pallet_area )

# Enforce no overlap on stack items. Distance between stack i and j equal or over to the sum of their radii.
for b in pallets:
    for i in range(len(group) - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(group)):
            # sqrt( (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 ) >= r2+r1 
            solver.Equation( (cx[(j,b)]-cx[(i,b)])**2 + 
                             (cy[(j,b)]-cy[(i,b)])**2 >= 
                             (radii[j] + radii[i])**2 )

"""
Objective
"""
# Minimize the number of bins used.
solver.Minimize( solver.sum( [y[b] for b in pallets] ) )

"""
Solve
"""
solver.options.SOLVER = 3
solver.solve( disp=True )

solver.options.SOLVER = 1
solver.solve( disp=True )
    
"""
Parse solution
"""
print(x)
print(y)
```

Outputs of the example cases:

```
Item IDs:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Item radii:  [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]
Item areas:  [0.12568, 0.12568, 0.12568, 0.12568, 0.12568, 0.12568]
Pallet IDs:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Pallet length:  1.2
Pallet width:  0.8
Pallet area:  0.96
x: {
    (0, 0): [0.0], (0, 1): [0.0], (0, 2): [1.0], (0, 3): [0.0], (0, 4): [0.0], (0, 5): [0.0], 
    (1, 0): [0.0], (1, 1): [0.0], (1, 2): [1.0], (1, 3): [0.0], (1, 4): [0.0], (1, 5): [0.0], 
    (2, 0): [0.0], (2, 1): [0.0], (2, 2): [1.0], (2, 3): [0.0], (2, 4): [0.0], (2, 5): [0.0], 
    (3, 0): [0.0], (3, 1): [0.0], (3, 2): [1.0], (3, 3): [0.0], (3, 4): [0.0], (3, 5): [0.0], 
    (4, 0): [0.0], (4, 1): [0.0], (4, 2): [1.0], (4, 3): [0.0], (4, 4): [0.0], (4, 5): [0.0], 
    (5, 0): [0.0], (5, 1): [0.0], (5, 2): [1.0], (5, 3): [0.0], (5, 4): [0.0], (5, 5): [0.0]
}
y: {0: [0.0], 1: [0.0], 2: [1.0], 3: [0.0], 4: [0.0], 5: [0.0]}
Bin number 2
        Items packed: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Number of bins used: 1
Time =  0.1022  seconds
```

```
Item IDs:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Item radii:  [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]
Item areas:  [0.12568, 0.12568, 0.12568, 0.12568, 0.12568, 0.12568]
Pallet IDs:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Pallet length:  0.8
Pallet width:  0.8
Pallet area:  0.64

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\k416262\Documents\thesis\code\thesisCode\main.py", line 87, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\k416262\Documents\thesis\code\thesisCode\main.py", line 70, in main
    order = createPallets_GEKKO(order, group, dims)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\k416262\Documents\thesis\code\thesisCode\packingGekko.py", line 89, in createPallets_GEKKO
    solver.solve( disp=False )
  File "C:\Users\k416262\Documents\thesis\code\thesisCode\venv\Lib\site-packages\gekko\gekko.py", line 2140, in solve
    raise Exception(apm_error)
Exception: @error: Solution Not Found
```

Can you spot a flaw in my code or logic, or is this a problem where the solver is just really not able to find a solution?

The end goal is to use this model for cases with tens of pallets and items, so this solution should really be scalable.

Answer (score 1):

One strategy is to solve the problem for a larger pallet and then use that solution as an initial guess for a smaller pallet. An additional decision variable could be the size of the pallet that is also minimized. This way, the size of the pallet is chosen to create a feasible solution. Yet another way is to allow overlap of the objects and then successively penalize the overlap to help find a solution and avoid the error of "no solution found".

Here is a related [circle packing optimization](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/CircleChallenge):

[image: Circle Packing]

Running the original code above gives an error that `name 'group' is not defined`. Please include a complete example problem that reproduces the error on your next question for a more complete answer.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I actually implemented a similar strategy, where I run the calculation for each available pallet size, since running with one size at a time is much faster. Then I select the size that resulted in least pallets used, preferring the smaller sizes. Finally as a last step, each pallet which has x-% capacity left can be checked if the items would fit inside a smaller pallet, if available